# Dimensions of matrices in implicit function theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

This isn't so much a intuition question as it is making sure I understand the dimensions of the matrices involved.

I'll start with the definition provided in class

> **Implicit Function Theorem**
> Consider a system of equations $f(x;q)=\vec{0}$. Let $D_x f(x_0;q_o)$ be non-singular. Then there exists a function $\hat x(q)$ defined at a neighborhood of the solution $(x_0, q_0)$ such that $f(\hat x(q),q)=\vec 0$ and furthermore $D_q \hat x (q) = -[D_xf(x;q)]^{-1} D_q f(x;q)$ for all $x,q$ in that neighborhood of $x_0, q_0$.

I'm pretty sure I understand most of this. we don't want a function in terms of $x$ and $q$ so we define the function $\hat x(q)$ to be an approximation of $x$ is terms of $q$. I mainly want to go over the dimensions of the systems from start to finish...

Let's say that $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and the number of equations in our system is $m$.

- $f(x;q)$ will be a $m \times 1$ vector.
- $D_x f(x_0, q_o)$ will be $m \times n$. It's a little confusing this matrix was called "non-singular". I think we're assuming that $m=n$ and there are no redundant equations... Right?
- $\hat x (q)$  will be the same dim as $x$ which is a $m \times 1$ vector.
- $D_q \hat x (q)$ is the same size as $[D_xf(x;q)]^{-1} D_q f(x;q)$ but I'm not 100% sure I have understand why that's the case... $D_q \hat x (q)$ will be $m \times n$ because we're taking the partial of the $m$ equations with respect to each of the $n$ components of $x$... $D_xf(x;q)$ must be square to take the inverse so although it looks like it's $m\times n$, we need to remember that $m = n$ and then $D_q f(x;q)$ is $m\times n$ again... but since $m=n$ we can just say, for simplicity that it's $n \times m$. So putting it together we see the RHS is $m \times m$ and the left side is $m\times n = m\times m$

Is all that correct? I don't feel very comfortable with it so looking for some confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in the case of $f(x,q) = Ax+bq$. Then ${\partial f(x,q) \over \partial x} = A, {\partial f(x,q) \over \partial q} = B$.

Note that the solution is $x = -A^{-1} B q$ (which should remind you of
$-({\partial f(x,q) \over \partial x})^{-1} {\partial f(x,q) \over \partial q}$).

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^m,q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then we must have $A: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (that is, a square matrix of size $m$)
and $B : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and so
$f: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: That's a much more succinct way of thinking about it. Thank you! If you wouldn't mind helping me connect the dots a little more, why are we thinking of our system of equation as $f(x,q)$ as the sum of two matrix transformations? Or is this more analogous to after we've differentiated $f$?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'd feel more comfortable if the first line said $f'(x,q) = Ax + Bq$ but if that's incorrect let me know haha

Comment: This is really the simplest form that $f(x,q)$ can take. (Not $f'$!!). The point is that to get intuition use a linear (or affine) model, then you don't need the fixed point machinery to establish the result.

Comment: To a first approximation, you will have $f(x+\delta, q+h) \approx f(x,q)+ {\partial f(x,q) \over \partial x}\delta + {\partial f(x,q) \over \partial q} h$.